# Get the value from the response based on a condition and store it to a variable

Tags: karate

I would like to get the value from the response based on a condition and store it to a variable.

In the below JSON, I would like to store the value when the name matches to something I prefer. Is there a way to achieve this using Karate API?

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "Sample1",
      "email": "sample1@text.com",
      "id": "U-123"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sample2",
      "email": "sample2@text.com",
      "id": "U-456"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sample3",
      "email": "sample3@text.com",
      "id": "U-789"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the question, so I pass

Comment: @PeterThomas My question is, if my response is in the above format. I would like to store the variable 'id' only when it matches the variable 'name = sample2 or something like this'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading the comment, my interpretation is to "find" the `id` where `name` is `Sample2`. Easy, just use a `filter()` operation, refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#jsonpath-filters

Instead of using a filter, I'm using the JS Array `find()` method as a very concise example below:

```
* def response =
"""
{ "results": [
    { "name": "Sample1", "email": "sample1@text.com", "id": "U-123" },
    { "name": "Sample2", "email": "sample2@text.com", "id": "U-456" },
    { "name": "Sample3", "email": "sample3@text.com", "id": "U-789" }
  ]
}
"""
* def id = response.results.find(x => x.name == 'Sample2').id
* match id == 'U-456'
```

Take some time to understand how it works. Talk to someone who knows JS if needed.